# Running twisted daemon with custom configuration

Tags: python, twisted

When I write a twisted service that will run with the `twistd` daemon I also want to make it configurable and run separate daemons, for the same service, with different configurations. But the `twistd` daemon does not accept (at least I don't see how) custom arguments from the command line, so what I do is to pass the configuration file in the standard input:

```
twisd -y myservice.py < my.cfg
```

and then in the `myservice.py` I have the following:

```
cfg = parseConfig(sys.stdin.read())
application = Application('myapp')
MyService(a=cfg.a, b=cfg.b).setServiceParent(application)
```

This is working just fine for me, but I'm wondering if there is The Right Way for doing this?

Comment: Reading from stdin in a tac file is unusual and not specifically supported.  It works by accident.  I think you'll have trouble convincing enough people that this is a good enough interface to explicitly support indefinitely - so you might find that a future release of Twisted (accidentally) breaks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the Twisted way of doing this is documented here:

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/howto/tap.html

You write plugins that add 'subcommands' which can be used via the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add one more option without the plugin mechanism, and avoiding the `stdio` - namely via the env variables:

```
CONFIG my.cfg twisd -y myservice.py
```

with the modified code:

```
cfg = parseConfig(open(os.environ['CONFIG']).read())
```

(I didn't think of this earlier because of my limited linux experience.)